# Using global variables in python function

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm going through [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-3-longest-increasing-subsequence/) solution for the Longest Increasing Subsequence problem and noticed that the global variable for the maximum value of the sub sequence length is being redefined both in the driver that runs the main function as well as in the actual function that computes the longest sub sequence:

```
# global variable to store the maximum
global maximum

def _lis(arr , n ):

    # to allow the access of global variable
    global maximum

    # Base Case
    if n == 1 :
        return 1

    # maxEndingHere is the length of LIS ending with arr[n-1]
    maxEndingHere = 1

    """Recursively get all LIS ending with arr[0], arr[1]..arr[n-2]
       IF arr[n-1] is maller than arr[n-1], and max ending with
        arr[n-1] needs to be updated, then update it"""

    for i in xrange(1, n):
        res = _lis(arr , i)
        if arr[i-1] < arr[n-1] and res+1 > maxEndingHere:
            maxEndingHere  = res +1

    # Compare maxEndingHere with overall maximum.And update
    # the overall maximum if needed
    maximum = max(maximum , maxEndingHere)

    return maxEndingHere

def lis(arr):

    # to allow the access of global variable
    global maximum

    # lenght of arr
    n = len(arr)

    # maximum variable holds the result
    maximum = 1

    # The function _lis() stores its result in maximum
    _lis(arr , n)

    return maximum
```

It would seem that each time a recursive call is made, the maximum value would be reset. What would be the purpose of redefining the global variables within the local scope of the functions?

Comment: That value should just be passed into the method... Maybe coding style? I think that is bad practice though. I lean toward if you are using a global variable you're probably doing it wrong...

Comment: Are you expecting `global` to reset the value of the global variable? I don't see anything I'd describe as "resetting" the maximum in `_lis`.

Comment: @user2357112, look just above the **return**.

Comment: @Prune: I wouldn't describe that as "resetting" the maximum.

Comment: A good example, why `global` makes code less understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `global` keyword in a function to be able to change the variable globally; if you do not use the keyword, it will create a variable of local scope with the same name. The statement `global maximum` does not “re-define” the variable, but it tells Python that if in this function `maximum` is set to some value, the global variable is meant to change.

```
In [1]: a = 42

In [2]: def f():
   ...:     a = 23
   ...:

In [3]: f()

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 42

In [5]: def g():
   ...:     global a
   ...:     a = 23
   ...:

In [6]: g()

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 23
```

Comment: The question is on the *definition* (value) of the variable, not its declaration.

Comment: I think that the person who asked the question misinterpreted the `global` keyword as “defining” something and that the question is actually about the use of the `global` keyword.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted this, and I wouldn't have because this response directly answers the question. Also, when I first learned python, I was taught that the use of global variables should be avoided. How could the code for these functions be structured such that a global variable isn't used?

Comment: You could change `_lis()` so that it accepts the parameter `maximum` and returns two values: the value it is returning already plus the current maximum value. Then you do not need a global variable. The code could look like this: https://gist.github.com/gandaro/8e9d146fadc69eed00b2

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code structure: there is no recursive call to **lis**; when it initializes maximum = 1 at line 42, that's the *only* time this statement is executed.  Everything else is done within **_lis**, where the maximum is only updated, never reset to 1.

I recommend that you find other code to study.  This example shows bad habits in handling the variables **maximum** and **arr** -- the author ignores the power of recursion here, using loop-style logic.  You could make a nice class exercise out of upgrading this to a program easy to read and maintain.

---

In dynamic programming, the only global variables should be for memoization.  In fact, this example uses *no* memoization -- which means it is *not* dynamic programming.  In short, there should be a memo list, where memo[n] holds the value from _lis(arr, n).  Recursive calls should not go farther than one level deep, as **_lis** will return this stored value.  The answer at the end is simply **max(memo)**.

See the WIkipedia pages on [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Dynamic_programming_in_computer_programming) and [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: I think the for loop is required in the top down approach for dynamic programming. How would you solve the problem without the for loop and how would you update the maximum variable?

Comment: It's not so much the existing **for** loop; it's the approach of the recursion.  **maximum** is an ugly clart in this respect, as is the static use of **arr** -- it's never changed from one call to the next, which tastes like another global variable.